# Failed opening 'Mage/Enterprise/Enterprise/Model/Observer.php' for inclusion

Tags: event-observer, log, varien-file-uploader

I have this warning every second in the system.log file of magento.
I made a copy of the prod in dev site, but no such error in the log file.
Does someone have a solution?

```
11271 2015-02-13T21:42:22+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 
'Mage/Enterprise/Enterprise/Model/Observer.php' for inclusion (include_path='/www/xxxxxx.com/files/html/app/code/local:/www/xxxxxx.com/files/html/app/code/community:/www/xxxxxx.com/files/html/app/code/core:/www/xxxxxx.com/files/html/lib:.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /www/xxxxxx.com/files/html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
    11272 2015-02-13T21:42:22+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Mage/Enterprise/Enterprise/Model/Observer.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /www/xxxxxx.com/files/html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
    11273 2015-02-13T21:42:22+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Mage/Enterprise/Enterprise/Model/Observer.php' for inclusion (include_path='/www/xxxxxx.com/files/html/app/code/local:/www/xxxxxx.com/files/html/app/code/community:/www/xxxxxx.com/files/html/app/code/core:/www/xxxxxx.com/files/html/lib:.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /www/xxxxxx.com/files/html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
    11274 2015-02-13T21:42:22+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Mage/Enterprise/Enterprise/Model/Observer.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /www/xxxxxx.com/files/html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
```

These are some observer.php files in local

```
app/code/local/GoMage/Navigation/Model/Observer.php
app/code/local/GoMage/Navigation/Model/Enterprise/Search/Observer.php
app/code/local/LC/CustomShipping/Model/Observer.php
app/code/local/LC/CustomShipping/Model/Sales/Quote/Observer.php
app/code/local/MageWorx/CustomOptions/Model/Observer.php
app/code/local/MageWorx/OrdersPro/Model/Observer.php
app/code/local/MageWorx/OrdersPro/Model/AwOrdertags/Observer.php
app/code/local/Magestore/Magenotification/Model/Observer.php
app/code/local/Magestore/Socialrecommend/Model/Observer.php
```

Comment: Were you able to solve the problem? Please take your time to accept an answer if it helped you

Answer (score 1):

Are you running Magento Enterprise?

- If no, an extension is trying to use the Magento Enterprise observer `enterprise_enterprise/observer`. Search for this string in `code` to find the problem.
- If yes, the file `app/code/core/Enterprise/Enterprise/Observer.php` seems to be missing or not readable. Magento then falls back to `Mage_...` and still finds nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Can you give any more information? Is it affecting any pages on the site or only showing in the error log?

1. If you browse to `app/code/core/Mage/Enterprise/Enterprise/Model/` does the `Observer.php` file exist? If not in `app/code/core/` also check `app/code/community/` and `app/code/local/`
2. Check folder & file permissions as well as ownership. Folders should typically be 755 and files should be 644.

Comment: Hi winston, I have no folder pp/code/core/Mage/Enterprise. this is the observer files in app/code/local app/code/local/GoMage/Navigation/Model/Observer.php
app/code/local/GoMage/Navigation/Model/Enterprise/Search/Observer.php
app/code/local/LC/CustomShipping/Model/Observer.php
app/code/local/LC/CustomShipping/Model/Sales/Quote/Observer.php
app/code/local/MageWorx/CustomOptions/Model/Observer.php
app/code/local/MageWorx/OrdersPro/Model/Observer.php
app/code/local/MageWorx/OrdersPro/Model/AwOrdertags/Observer.php

Comment: Your site should definitely have an `app/code/core/` folder. That is where all the "core" parts of Magento are found. If you have things in `app/code/local/` or `app/code/community/` those typically just override what is found in the `app/code/core/`. Is the site currently working despite the error message?

If you do not have the core directory you might try download the same version of Magento and copying that directory into your installation. Is there a link you can share for the site?

Comment: Hi Winston, Sorry, I know what you said. What I told to you is what there are not folder Enterprise/Enterprise in local, nor in community, nor in core

Answer (score 0):

If you have converted from an EE store to a CE store, you might start by exploring the following...

There are cron jobs in the core_config_data table:

```
select * from core_config_data where path like '%cron%'
```

You may find that you have the following rows:

```
increment, default, 0, crontab/jobs/send_notification/schedule/cron_expr, */15 * * * *
```

and

```
increment, default, 0, crontab/jobs/send_notification/run/model, enterprise_reminder/observer::scheduledNotification
```

Running this sql command should cause your error to stop:

```
delete from core_config_data where path like '%send_notification%'
```

Ensure you also clear cache and even go so far as to execute in bash:

```
rm /var/www/var/cache/* -rf
```

Also, feel free to truncate the cron_schedule table.  It will repopulate on its own if your cron jobs are set up properly.

If you don't feel like doing something that drastic to a production site (I just did it to my dev environment), you can install

https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_Scheduler

This can help you visualize current cron jobs that aren't obvious parts of crontab.  You can disabled them with this plugin... I think.